# How to create a list from a specific object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object:

```
const myObject = {
property1: ['apple', 'peach'],
property2: ['blue', 'red']
}
```

What I want to do is to create a list in a Table where I list on each row, the key name and right below, every elements of the corresponding array. Something like:

```
<li>property1</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>peach</li>
<li>property2</li>
<li>blue</li>
<li>red</li>
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please explore using `Object.entries()`, and `.map()`. Documentations are available here -> [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear whether you want a list or a table. But here's a quick example of a bulleted list using your data.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const data = {
  property1: ['apple', 'peach'],
  property2: ['blue', 'red']
};

// Simple function to mock an API response
function mockApi() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// Create a list, and then `map` over the object
// entries. Use the key as a list heading, and then
// `map` over the values of the array to create a new list.
function Example() {

  // Initialise state
  const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);

  // Get the data after two seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    mockApi()
      .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
      .then(data => setState(data));
  }, []);

  // If there is no state return "No data"
  if (!state) return <div>No data</div>;

  // Otherwise `map` over the object entries
  // setting each key as the header, and `mapping`
  // over the values array
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(state).map(([key, arr]) => {
        return (
          <li>
            {key}
            <ul>
              {arr.map(el => <li>{el}</li>)}
            </ul>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    property1: ['apple', 'peach'],
    property2: ['blue', 'red'],
}

const data = [];

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, values]) => {    
  data.push(key)
  if (Array.isArray(values)) {
    data.push(...values)
  }
});

return (
  <ul>
    {data.map(str => <li>{str}</li>)}
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I wonder if the object comes from a GET call, if (...values) won't give me an error such as "cannot iterate through undefined"...

Comment: indeed, obj comes from an useEffect hook where I defined const[obj, setObj] = useState({})

Comment: @Obiadi I added a check if it's an array, may it help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this one. State is here.

```
   const [records, setRecords] = useState(
   [
     { id: 1, content: "property1"},
     { id: 2, content: "apple"},
     { id: 3, content: "peach"},
     { id: 4, content: "property2"},
     { id: 5, content: "blue"}
   ]);
```

Return method is here.

```
return (
 <>
   <ul>
   {
     records.map(r =>
     <li>  {r.id + " " + r.content} </li>
     )
   }
   </ul>
</>
);
```